# How to add a user’s name when we sign up with fire base auth

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for the first time. I am learning through the firebase docs. I am using firebase.auth.signUserUpWithEmailAndPassword() I have heard that we can also give a photo url and and username to firebase auth. How can we do that. I was not able to find it in the docs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions on Stack Overflow.  You were given an answer before.  If something isn't working the way you expect, your question should show the specific code that isn't working, along with debugging details.

Comment: I repeated my question because I was told that usernames cannot be given. However, I found information that username can be given. That's why I aksed again.

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  It's generally expected that you make an attempt at solving your problem, then post the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Or at least focus the question on a specific programming or design issue.  I gave you links for updating the profile URL, as well as advice on how to store images if that's what you need.  It's up to you to start writing code to implement that.